# Webfont relationship between css.content and Unicode

Tags: javascript, html, css, unicode, woff

I am trying to understand the relationships between css.content and webfonts unicode values.

I am using the office-ui-fabric.css
https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/11.0.0/css/fabric.min.css

This loads a Webfont:
https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/assets/icons/fabricmdl2icons-3.54.woff

Selecting the Contrast Icon has a content of `"îž¡"`

```css
.ms-Icon--Contrast:: before {
     content: "îž¡";
}
```

looking at the webfont I see that there is a unicode value for this icon

```
<glyph glyph-name="uniE7A1" unicode="&#xe7a1;"
```

console.logging the glyph

```
console.log("".charCodeAt(0).toString(16)) //=>e7a1
```

How can I convert css.content `"îž¡"` to `uniE7A1` or `"&#xe7a1;"` in javasccript?
I would like to find the relationships between those values

Comment: is this same icon set? most of the time we have simple DEMO page we can use to get unicode value for any icon https://uifabricicons.azurewebsites.net/  in the top right if you click and select second option called: Detail, it gives you table of all icons with their unicodes next to it. Or you are looking for something else?

Comment: Yes, I know how to get the values it. But I am trying to understand how `"îž¡"` translates to `"&#xe7a1;"`

Comment: It doesn’t; it’s the result of an error. U+E7A1 in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is `<0xEE, 0x9E, 0xA1>`. If you then re-interpret these same bytes as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), you get “îž¡” instead.

Comment: This gets mit in the right direction. How would I convert `U+E7A1` to `îž¡` in node so I would be able to compare them? Please write as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Why would you want to compare them? “îž¡” is not the icon you need; it’s a random string of characters resulting from your browser interpreting the CSS file as the wrong encoding. “îž¡” is just three bytes read as if they were characters in Windows-1252, which they should not be. The same three bytes, when read as UTF-8, become  – the character you actually want.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation. What I realize now is that when I look at the same css rule in the browser it shows , when I look at it in the editor I see “îž¡”, even though the file is utf8 encoded.

Comment: @Delcon If you are sure the editor is using UTF-8, then there was an encoding error somewhere. The only way to know for sure what's in the file is to look at it with a hex viewer. Then your options depend on what else is in the file. Many editors check on opening if a file contains only valid UTF-8, and if not, they conclude it's probably Windows-1252 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found out, I hope it helps somebody:

As @CharlotteBuff pointed out, in Chrome, clicking on the .css and viewing in the browser, or right click and download saves the .css with a Windows Codepage. Looking at it in UTF8 VsCode will not get you far... You need to download it with curl or, in my case Javascript.

After you have mastered this you still want or need to convert, this will help you do it in Javascript:

```
//----unicode------
//unicode Value from String
var unicodeValue = "".codePointAt(0)
console.log(unicodeValue) //59297

//string from unicode
let str = String.fromCharCode(59297)
console.log(str) //""


//----hex----
//hex value from string
let hex = "".codePointAt(0).toString(16)
console.log(hex) // e7a1

//string from hex
let str = String.fromCharCode(parseInt("e7a1", 16))
console.log(str) //""
```